# AmCharts stock chart Cursor Date

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I am using Amcharts Javascript charts to display a stock chart. I would like to display custom text in the Category Cursor Balloon. However, currently only date format can be defined, using

```
categoryBalloonDateFormats
```

Is there a way to write a separate text item for each point on the category axis?

Thanks, 
Ernst

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible at the moment, but in next update we will introduce a categoryBalloonFunction property which will allow formatting your own balloon text and return in to the balloon. The new release will soon be available (most likely during this week).